# Some trivial questions about Tangent Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm studying submanifolds $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and now I've got some questions about tangent spaces.

**First question:**
Let $\gamma:I\subset\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a path, which means $\gamma(t) \in M,  \forall t \in I$. Now I have some trouble to completely understand the concept of a tangent vector. According to my notes a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a tangent vector to $M$in $x\in M$ if there exists a path $\gamma: I \to M$ where $\gamma(t_0) = x$ and $\gamma'(t_0)=v$

How can I get the intuition of this?

**Second Question**:
The Tangent Space is the set of all tangent vecotrs to $M$ in a point $x\in M$. If $h: V\subset \mathbb{R}^k \to M\cap U$, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, is a local parametrisation, and $h(\hat x) = x$, then

$$T_xM = \text{ im }D_{\hat x}h = \{D_{\hat x}\cdot u : u\in \mathbb{R}^k \} $$
On the other hand, I read somewhere that the tangent space is the nullspace of the Jacobian of $F$ is the submanifold is the set of solutions of the system of equations

$F_1(x_1, ..., x_n) = 0; ....; F_r(x_1, ... , X_n)=0$

How can I relate those two definitions? I think it's not that hard at all but I cannot see it :-). Examples are desirable! Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, you can get rid of the first sentence and just look at the second one.

A tangent vector to the unit sphere at the north point $P$ is a path $\gamma$ whose image lies on the sphere and which passes through $P$ at time $0$ (or $t_0$ in your definition).

That doesn't seem to mesh with your intuition that a tangent vector is a little arrow starting at the north pole and having no north-south component, right?

Well, suppose you had such a vector, like $v = (1.3, 2, 0)$ (I'm assuming that $z$ points from the south pole to the north pole here). What would be the corresponding $\gamma$? It'd be a path headed through the north pole with $\gamma'(0) = v$. Letting 
$$
w = v / \| v \|
$$
you could define such a $\gamma$ by 
$$
\gamma(t) = \cos(\|v\| t) (0, 0, 1) + \sin(\|v\| t) w.
$$

Of course, there are many others that would work equally well. But there's no way to pick a curve $\gamma$ in the sphere whose derivative $\gamma'(0)$ as it passes through $P$ is, say, $(0, 0, 1)$. So what I've done is provide a correspondence between the intuitive notion ("a little arrow") and the formal one. In one direction, it's $\gamma \mapsto \gamma'(0)$; in the other, it's $$v \mapsto (t \mapsto \cos(\|v\| t) (0,0,1) + \sin(\|v\| t) \frac{v}{\|v\|}.$$ 
The two correspondences are inverses of one another.

For the torus, or some more complex objects, defining the second map is a pain in the neck -- you generally need to apply the inverse/implicit function theorems -- but the idea is the same.

Why on earth would someone define "tangent vector" this way? Well, because in a little while (like in a later chapter of your book), you'll be looking at manifolds that don't necessarily sit inside $R^n$; for those, you'll define an tangent vector at $P$ to be an equivalence class of curves that pass through $P$ at time $t = 0$, where the equivalence is carefully defined to match the notion of "have the same derivative at t = 0" definition in the case where the manifold actually *is* sitting in $R^n$.

For the second question... well, let's again look at a simple case: the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $R^2$. Here the implicit definition of $M$ is $F(x, y) = 0$, where $F(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$.  The various things you've required to be zero are the partial derivatives of $F$. At the north pole $(0, 1)$ of the unit circle, these are $F_1(0, 1) = 2x|_{x = 0} = 0$ and $F_2(0, 1) = 2$. That doesn't quite make sense. What you really want to say is, I think, that $v$ is a tangent vector if $F_1(P) \cdot v = 0, \ldots, F_r(P) \cdot v = 0$; in our case, that'd turn into 
$$
[0, 2] \cdot v = 0
$$
i.e., $v$ would have to be a multiple of $[1, 0]$ which makes intuitive sense. Indeed, in the case where your manifold is defined by one implicit function $F$, the gradient of $F$ is usually descrribed as "the direction in which $F$ changes fastest"; that's perpendicular to the directions in which $F$ changes slowest, i.e., the directions "along the manifold." So the conditon that $\nabla F \cdot v = 0$ is exactly the requirement that $v$ be perpendicular to the "normal vector" to the surface, which (I hope) makes some intuitive sense as a "tangent vector".

By the way, suppose that $M$ is defined by $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$, and $\gamma:[-1, 1] \to M$ is a smooth curve in $M$. Then for all $t$, we have 
$$
F(\gamma(t)) = 0
$$
Differentiate the expression above at $t = 0$, and let $P$ denote $\gamma(0)$. Then on the one hand, $\gamma'(0)$ is supposed to denote a tangent vector at $P$. On the other, by the chain rule we have
$$
\nabla F(P) \cdot \gamma'(0) = 0
$$
so that $\gamma'(0)$ is in fact perpendicular to this normal (i.e., satisfies a slightly modified version of the equations you wrote).